# If I had a matrix A, what is the meaning of $A^T Ax$, given $A^T$ is transpose of A and x are vectors of variable?

Tags: matrices, transpose

If I had a matrix $A$, what is the meaning of $A^TAx$, given $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$ and $x$ is a vector?

Is it operation on $x$ by the result of the multiplication of two matrices, or is it operation on $x$ first by $A$, then by $A^T$?

Comment: Note that matrix product is associative.

Comment: You know, on this site, if you recieve an answer that you were looking for, you can accept it. If it is not, you can comment to explain what is still missing.

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping. Ya this is what I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. Because $(A^TA)x = A^T(Ax)$.